# System.Deployment.Application ApplicationDeployment with a Proxy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, proxy

I am using ClickOnce for a C# Windows Forms application, and want to allow people to update the software by clicking an Update button, which will check the server online to see if there are any updates. I am using the following method (not exact, but same principle):

```
ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
ad.CheckForUpdateProgressChanged += new DeploymentProgressChangedEventHandler(ad_CheckForUpdateProgressChanged);
ad.CheckForUpdateCompleted += new CheckForUpdateCompletedEventHandler(ad_CheckForUpdateCompleted);
ad.CheckForUpdateAsync();
```

This all works fine, the problem is trying to run this code from behind a proxy. A 407 error: Proxy Authentication required occurs. I can't find anywhere in the ApplicationDeployment class to enter proxy settings, even though ad.CheckForUpdateAsync() simply does a webrequest to the server (I assume). Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect it'll use whatever the default proxy settings are configured in IE... Is this not the case?

Comment: Nope, I have the proxy set up in IE (internet options), it doesn't work :(